# border-collapse: collapse not working properly when scaling

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove the border of a table using `border-collapse: collapse`. It works great and as it should, but when I start doing `transform: scale()` to make it smaller, the borders magically appear again.

https://jsfiddle.net/ox11pvag/

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;

    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -o-transform: scale(0.6);
    -o-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    transform: scale(0.6);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

Is there a way to force the borders to collapse no matter what? I assume overlapping them (negative margin) is a way, but it sounds so dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When browser is scaling the table it is not making exact calculations for the width of `td` elements. As a result there is some gap between adjacent `td` elements and background of parent element is visible through this gap which looks like `td` elements have borders(But actually its gap, if you will apply some `background-color` on parent you will see it).

You can fix this by doing the following changes:

1. Remove `background` of `tbody tr:nth-child(odd)` and apply it to `table`.
2. Add `2px` or `3px` `border-right` having the color same as `background` on `td` inside even rows and inside `thead`.

Working snippet is below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: #7892a1;
  width: 70%;
}

thead {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

tbody tr {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

thead {
  background: #d2dbe0;
}

thead th {
  border-right: 2px solid #d2dbe0;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #a5b7c0;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  border-right: 2px solid #a5b7c0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Something</th>
    <th>Something 2</th>
    <th>Something 3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some data</td>
      <td>Some more data</td>
      <td>Most data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some data</td>
      <td>Some more data</td>
      <td>Most data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some data</td>
      <td>Some more data</td>
      <td>Most data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Heh, yeah I figured I had to do some hacky trick in order to get it to work. Thanks though.